# React-Native(Place Icons inside VictoryScatter)

Tags: react-native

Hello i would like to ask how i can place an icon(react-native-vector-icons) inside a graph(VictoryScatter)in react-native...What i want to get is simply some icons and then connect them(their positions with VictoryLine)

e.g.
      `class CatPoint extends React.Component {
          render() {
           const {x, y, datum} = this.props; // VictoryScatter supplies x, y and 
                                                      datum
           const cat = datum._y >= 0 ? "" : "";
            return (
             
              {cat}
             
            );
           }
          }

```
    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
       return (
         <VictoryChart>
          <VictoryScatter
           dataComponent={<CatPoint/>}
            y={(d) => Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * d.x)}
            samples={15}
          />
         </VictoryChart>
      );
     }
    }
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, mountNode);`
```

I want something like this but instead of this icons i want to add some react-native vector icons